# TensorFlow: Change a variable while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, input

if I change my input pipeline from feed_dict{...} to a tf.data.dataset how can I change the value of a parameter within the network during training after each iteration. To clarify, the old code would look something like this:

```
# Define Training Step:  

# model is some class that defines graph.   

def train_step(x_batch, y_batch, var):

        feed_dict = {
            model.input         : x_batch,
            model.labels        : y_batch,
            model.var_to_change : var,
        }
        _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
            [train_op, global_step, model.cross_entropy, model.accuracy],
            feed_dict)

# Training:  

var_new = 0 
for i in range(num_epochs):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        train_step(batch[0], batch[1], var_new) 
        var_new = something_new_for_each_iteration
```

For the new stuff it will look something like that:

```
model = create_model(dataset.inputs, dataset.outputs)
# where model.train returns tf.group(update_losses, train_op, global_step)

# Training

for step in range(num_epochs):

    fetches = {"train": model.train}
    results = sess.run(fetches, options=options)
```

Thank you!

Comment: providing minimum working example could help to find the answer. Currently I'm not totally sure what exactly is required. Nevertheless posting a couple of options in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved the issue: I initialised the parameter as a [tf.Variable()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) with a certain name. Then after running my session I looped through [tf.global_variables()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables) to find it and used variable.load(new_variable, sess) to change its value. I included the variable in my summaries and its value is changing. Also the layer weights that this interpolation parameter adds to the network start to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, maybe one of following options would fit:

1. You could create separate model feature for this parameter and generate it's values during training using the [Dataset.from_generator()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)
2. If the variable can be computed from the previous step, you could create a variable in the graph and update it using [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) operation. During the next batch you could read and use the updated value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had problems using tf.assign because it gave me an error message that the graph is finalised. I think I resolved the issue, details in my own answer.