# How to preprocess images using Tensorflow.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My goal is to prepare a tf.data.Dateset from a list of image paths and some metadata. I need to preprocess images (flip) based on the metadata, so not every image is preprocessed in the same way.

So far I've tried the following approach:

1. Build the initial dataset from a list.

```py
    train_ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_samples)
```

where train_samples is n x [img_path, label, 'RIGHT' / 'LEFT'] list.

2. Transform it to the final form using the map function.

   ```
   def _process_sample(self, sample):
      img_path = join(self.main_folder, sample[0])
      img = load_img(img_path)

      if sample[2] == 'R':
          img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

      img = img.resize(input_shape)

      input_array = img_to_array(img)
      input_array /= 255.0

      return input_array, sample[1]

   train_ds = train_ds.map(self._process_sample)
   ```

I know that sample is a Tensor and I cannot just access the value in the graph mode. I also know that I could run the code in the eager mode, but I don't want to lose the performance.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Before you do `from_tensor_slices()`, do your flips on the images, then use that method.

Comment: @Djinn In my application, I need to display the images as they are. This is why I want to preprocess them on the fly to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: When you say on the fly, do you mean during training? Or before? If during, [maybe this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635806/tensorflow-change-a-variable-while-training) can help? If you need it before training, you can use tf functions similar to an array and (extract+)update images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints. I've finally solved it by using [tf.Dataset.from_generator()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator). Here is the working code:

```
def gen():
    for sample in train_samples:
        img_path = join(self.main_folder, sample[0])
        img = load_img(img_path)

        if sample[2] == 'R':
            img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

        img = img.resize(input_shape)

        input_array = img_to_array(img)
        input_array /= 255.0

        yield input_array, sample[1]

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int8))
```